# Question about induction to infinity with regard to Bolzano's philosophy

Tags: induction, philosophy

I'm a philosophy and mathematics student, and I'm writing a paper on a proof put forward by Bolzano that if we can know one thing to be true, then we can know infinite truths. Put simply, he states that if we know A to be true then the statement "A is true" is true, and the statement "'A is true', is true" is true, and so on. (There are a lot of problems with this but for now lets just focus on the maths of it)
Obviously this is a proof by induction. Russell writes about the inductive numbers as a subset of the natural numbers, and how we can't use induction to infinity, because each number the statement is true for must have a predecessor and successor, which are indefinable for ∞. Can someone explain this further, and possibly more correctly for me? Thanks!

Comment: See in [Bolzano's logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bolzano-logic/) : **4. Propositions and truths in themselves** : "There are infinitely many truths in themselves. Bolzano proposed several proofs for this claim, the simplest being the following. [...] Other proofs, by complete induction, are more sophisticated, but hardly more convincing."

Comment: What is not clear in your question is the refernce to Russell's "objection" ... It seems to me that what you are suggestiong is that $\infty$ is not a *natural* number, because it has no predecessor, and this is true. This implies that if we have proved by [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) that $P(n)$ holds for all *natural* numbers $n$, for some property $P$, we are not licensed to conclude with $P(\infty)$, and also this is true.

Comment: What I'm looking for is just some more material and information on the nature of induction and why we cannot conclude P(∞)

Comment: Why can't we say there are countably infinite truths, isn't there a bijection between the set of truths and the natural numbers?

Comment: In order to conclude  P(∞) we have to use [Transfinite induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction).

Answer (score 1):

[Mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) *per se* cannot prove the existence of an infinite set, like the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers*.

Usually, *induction* is assumed as an axiom "defining the essence" of our "intuitive" undertsanding of the succession of natural numbers.

The principle of *mathematical induction* is stated, in formal way, as :

> **if** $P(0)$ holds and, for any $n$, if $P(n)$ holds, then $P(n+1)$ holds, **then** $P(n)$ holds for any $n$.

The key-point is the "operation" $+1$ which produce, for any number $n$, its *successor* $n+1$.

The weak-point of a proof like Bolzano's one (at least in his simplest form) is that induction is not enough to ensure *infinity*.

For clerness, call $s(x)$ the successor function and consider a simple "universe" $U$ with only two objects : $U = \{ 0,1 \}$ and define the *successor* as follows :

> $s(0)=1$ and $s(1)=0$.

Assume now a property $P$ such that : $P(0)$ holds and that : for any $n$, if $P(n)$ holds, then also $P(s(n))$ holds.

Mathematical induction licenses us to conclude that $P(n)$ holds for any $n$, i.e. that both $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ hold.

But our "universe" $U$ is **not** infinite.

Comment: Is there a way that we can show that transfinite induction cannot apply to the bolzano problem?

Comment: and also, while there is no ∞th truth, isnt the collection of truths an infinite set?

Comment: @123454321 - We can use *transfinite induction* indeed, but (see : [Set Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html)) again it does not prove the existence of an *infinite* set; this existence is provided (presupposed) in set theory by an axiom : the *Infinity Axiom*.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways of saying the same thing. Saying it in many ways does not express a new truth each time. So, yes, the number of ways of saying something is without theoretical bound; but, no, this "count" does not represent more than one truth.

Saying "$A$ is true", rather than saying what $A$ represents---a possibly long and complex statement---is a linguistic convention: a short sentence replaces a long one. In ordinary speech, rather than saying "$A$ is true", we would more likely say "it is true", "that is true", "what XY says is true", and so on, as long as the reference is clear from the context; we do not say just "it", "that", etc., because these are not sentences.